# Find all continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $f(x+y)=2+f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(3)=5$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> Find all continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ for which $f(3)=5$ and for every $x,y \in \mathbb R$ it is true that $f(x+y)=2+f(x)+f(y)$.

I tried to find some dependence before $x$ and $y$ because I have for example $f(1+2)=2+f(1)+f(2)=5$ and then $f(1)+f(2)=3$. However I cannot find dependence for every $x,y$ so I don't know how I can do this task.

I also thought about creating a new function $g$ which is dependent on $f$ but I also don't have a good idea to do this.

Can you get me some tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As transformed by @Hagen von Eitzen into the Cauchy functional equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). The only continous solution to Cauchy's functional equation is $g(x)=kx$. Therefore, $f(x)+2=kx$. Now given that $f(3)=5$ so that $k=\frac{7}{3}$. Thus the required function is $f(x)=\frac{7}{3}x-2$.

Comment: ok, but why I can assume that's this function is additive? Does she have to be like that? How to prove it?

Comment: It is not additive homomorphism but we have transformed it  to Cauchy's functional equation, which is additive.

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* With $g(x):=f(x)+2$, we have$$ g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y).$$